# error: std::string was not declared in this scope, in for loop C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, gmp

I was trying to implement code making use of the GMP library for a class, and haven't been able to figure out the source of this issue. I've run similar code before on an unordered_map so this error is confusing me. From what I can tell the std::string should be declared in the scope by the call to the for loop. Could it be related to using the GMP library?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
std::map<mpz_class, std::string> number_names;
std::ifstream names_file("/srv/datasets/number_names.txt");
if(!names_file.is_open()){
  std::cout << "error reading /srv/datasets/number_names.txt\n";
  return -1;
}
mpz_class num;
for (std::string name : names_file >> name >> num){ // line throwing error
  number_names[num] = name;
}
auto value = mpz_class(argv[1]);
std::vector<std::string> output = some_func(value, number_names);
```

}

the full error message reads:

```
    as10.cpp:75:43: error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope 
    75 |     for (std::string name : names_file >> name >> num)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `for (std::string name : names_file >> name >> num)` is valid syntax, but maybe I'm wrong. Maybe what you want is `std::string name; while(names_file >> name >> num)`?

Comment: `std::string name; while (names_file >> name >> num) number_names[num] = name;` should do the job. Your syntax is not how range based for loops work.

Comment: Please provide the input text file and also what is the intention of this program that is what output do you expect.

Comment: @mch that's strange i ran code like: `int mapValue;
for (char mapLetter; value_infile >> mapLetter >> mapValue;){
    scrabbleValues[mapLetter] = mapValue;
}` that ran as expected

Comment: @VinDiesel_ `:` is not `;`

Comment: yes, that's the old school for loop with the 2 `;`, you used the range based for loop with the 1 `:` in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cpp
for (std::string name : names_file >> name >> num){
  number_names[num] = name;
}
```

This is not how range-based for loop works in C++, so this is a syntax error. By the looks of it, you have a typo.

Maybe what you want is:

```cpp
std::string name;
while(names_file >> name >> num){
    number_names[num] = name;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
for (std::string name; names_file >> name >> num;){
    number_names[num] = name;
}
```